# How can I do route configuration in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routeconfig

How can I do route configuration as below?

My current url is: `http://localhost:4815/Home/ByCategory/1`

But I want it to be: `http://localhost:4815/CategoryTitle`

```
public ActionResult ByCategory(int? id)
{
    ...
}

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ByCategory", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I'm unclear about what this question is asking. Do you want to add another action to your controller, but an action that doesn't require an 'id' parameter?

Comment: When I click on the link, I don't want it to be 
http: // localhost: 4815 / Home / ByCategory / 1.
I want to 
http: // localhost: 4815 / CategoryTittle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your suggestions. I have added the following code to routeconfig. I used `<a href="/question"> </a>` on the view page to go to the relevant controller

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "AddQuestion",
               url: "AddQuestion",
               defaults: new { controller = "Question", action = "Create" }
           );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Attribute Routing`. for doing this at first you must Enable it by
adding below code top of your `MapRoute` in `RouteConfig`:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); //Enables Attribute Routing
```

then you can add `Attribute Routing` at top of your classes and methods:

```
 [Route("CategoryTitle")]
 public ActionResult ByCategory(int? id)
        {
           ...
        }
```

for deep dive in `Routing`, you can follow this [link](https://exceptionnotfound.net/attribute-routing-vs-convention-routing/).

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parametrize a route with Category Title, you can use Attribute Routing like so

```
[Route("~/{categoryTitle}")]
public ActionResult ByCategory(string categoryTitle)
...
```